# How to animate DIV onload through JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<script>
//Animation should start when the window loads

$(window).load(function(){
    $("div.container :nth-child(4)").animate({down: '50px'}, "fast");
});

//3rd DIV tag changes BG-color on mouseover & changes back on mouse leave

$("div.container :nth-child(3)").mouseover(function(){
    $("div.container :nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "yellow");
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("div.container :nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "white");
});

//1st DIV tag expands on click & resets on mouse leave

$("div.container :nth-child(1)").click(function(){
    $("div.container :nth-child(1)").css("width", "250px");
    $("div.container :nth-child(1)").css("height", "250px");
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("div.container :nth-child(1)").css("width", "150px");
    $("div.container :nth-child(1)").css("height", "150px");
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="border box"></div>
  <div class="border box"></div>
  <div class="border box"></div>
  <div class="border box"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried with $(window).load and $(document).ready and it does not work.
I want the animation to start when the page loads completely.

Comment: `down`??? that's not a valid css property.

Comment: i also tried with other sides and it does not work

Comment: All of your code needs to be in your `$(window).load()` or a `$(document).ready()` - your clicks, mousleaves, mouseovers, etc, won't work otherwise.

Comment: `down` is not valid property. You can use `bottom` instead. And make other fixes as mentioned in the other comment.

Comment: Are you using jquery UI?

Comment: No im not, im just trying to get all of the DIVs to move slowly from top to bottom as the page loads

Comment: `$(window).load()` is when all of the resources on the page have loaded. But you can defer loading or cause things to load after that, so other things may still be loading even if you put your code in `$(window).load()`.  If you put your animation in `$(window).load()` and there are still things loading on the page that you want to wait for, you need to  provide context in your post as to what's loading after `$(window).load()` and how it's loading after so we can help add the animation after those things load.

Comment: I have tried to add everything inside of  `$(document).ready()` and it's still not animating. `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.container").animate({bottom: '50px'}, "slow");`

Comment: Got it ! The problem was that i had to put `position: absolute` on DIV elements & now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
        .box{
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            border:2px solid red;
            float: left;
            display: block;

        }

    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="border box"></div>
      <div class="border box"></div>
      <div class="border box"></div>
      <div class="border box"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    //Animation should start when the window loads
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.container :nth-child(4)").animate({height: "+=50px"}, "slow");

    //3rd DIV tag changes BG-color on mouseover & changes back on mouse leave

    $("div.container :nth-child(3)").mouseover(function(){
        $("div.container :nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $("div.container :nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "white");
    });

    //1st DIV tag expands on click & resets on mouse leave

    $("div.container :nth-child(1)").click(function(){
        $("div.container :nth-child(1)").css("width", "250px");
        $("div.container :nth-child(1)").css("height", "250px");
    }).on('mouseleave',function(){
        $("div.container :nth-child(1)").css("width", "150px");
        $("div.container :nth-child(1)").css("height", "150px");
    });

    });
    </script>
```